# printing values from object

Tags: php

How do I echo the value from the object? In the following example I expect 1105 service number to be printed after "case".

```
    $vbk->set('service_no','1105');
    echo "case".$vbk->service_no;
```

I need to use object for this purpose.

Comment: What does it actually print? what does set do?

Comment: It prints case but I want it to print case1105 .
Any other way of printing this value from object will be OK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement a [__get](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#language.oop5.overloading.members) function which will handle that logic. When __get is called, it will look for our stored properties in `$properties` and return it if it's found. POC:

```
<?php
class service
{
    private $properties = array();
    
    public function set($key, $value)
    {
        $this->properties[$key] = $value;
    }
    
    public function __get($key)
    {
        if(isset($this->properties[$key]))
            return $this->properties[$key];
            
        return null;
    }
}

$service = new service;
$service->set('service_no','1105');

// case1105
echo "case".$service->service_no;
```

Comment: The default value would rather be `null` than an empty string.